# Calling to_json on an array with different methods on each object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sinatra

I have a sinatra service returning a json array of objects to my rails app. The objects are all of different types. I'm trying to pass the :methods option to the to_json call, but each object needs different methods called on it. The code below doesn't work, since I'm returning an array of json objects.

```
params = {:assets => {'1' => {:asset_type => "file", :urls => [:original]},
                      '2' => {:asset_type => "image", :urls => [:original, :thumbnail]}
                     }
         }

get 'url' do
  assets = []

  params[:assets].each do |asset_id,asset_params|
    asset = Asset.find asset_id
    methods = asset_params[:urls]
    asset_json = asset.to_json :methods => methods
    assets << asset_json
  end
  assets
end

#expected output:

[{"id" => 1, "type" => "file", "original" => "/filesystem/asset/1/filename.txt"}, {"id" => 2, "type => "image", "original" => "/filesystem/asset/2/image.jpg", "thumbnail" => "/filesystem/asset/2/image_thumb.jpg"}]
```

Is there a way I can just turn the assets array into json without doing so to each object in that array? Or some other way to return what I want? Thanks.

A solution a coworker suggested that seems to work, but is a bit hacky. The return value could be (since to_json is really just creating a string):

```
"[" + assets.join(',') + "]"
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the `params[:assets]` array and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: Don't return `assets`, but `assets.to_json`. (An ideal solution to this would involve not calling `to_json` for each asset but only once at the end.)

On a sidenote: Please don't ever say that `to_json` is "really just creating a string". If it were that easy, we wouldn't need the `json` gem.